# Guardar los resultados de una Calculadora PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Buenas tardes resulta que quiero guardar la operación a la hora de calcular lo he intentado pero no sale tengo el diseño, pero no se me guarda los números introducidos para el calculo y ese es el objetivo de esto.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Calculadora Javi</title>
    <link href="index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){

    } else {
        $operacion = $_POST['operacion'];
    }
    //$resultado = $_POST['Resultado'];
    echo "<br/>";
    echo '<h1>Calculadora Javi</h1>';
    echo '<br/>';
    //echo '<h2>1 - Sumar</h2>';
    //echo '<br>';
    //echo '<h2>2 - Restar</h2>';
    //echo '<br>';
    //echo '<h2>3 - Multiplicar</h2>';
    //echo '<br/>';
    //echo '<h2>4 - Dividir</h2>';
    //echo '<br/>';
    //echo '<h2>5 - Raiz Cuadrada</h2>';
    //echo '<br/>';
    //echo '<h2>6 - Porcentaje</h2>';
    //echo '<br/>';
    #echo '<p id>Introduce La operacion</p>';


?>
<center>
<table>
    <form method="post" action="calculadora.php">
    <tr>    
        <td>
            <label for="num">Operacion 1 : </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="num">
                <option value="Sumar">Suma</option>
                <option value="Restar">Resta</option>
                <option value="Multiplicar">Producto</option>
                <option value="Dividir">Divisor</option>
                <option value="Raiz Cuadrada">Raiz Cuadrada</option>
                <option value="Porcentaje">Porcentaje</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Numero 1 :   
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="A"size="8"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Numero 2 :   
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="B"size="8"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="resultados">Operacion 2 :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="resultados">
                <option value="Sumar">Suma</option>
                <option value="Restar">Resta</option>
                <option value="Multiplicar">Producto</option>
                <option value="Dividir">Divisor</option>
                <option value="Raiz Cuadrada">Raiz Cuadrada</option>
                <option value="Porcentaje">Porcentaje</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Numero 3 : 
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="C"size="8"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calcular" size="8" />
        </td>
        <td>
            
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</center>
    <!--- <form id='Centro' method="post" action="calculadora2.php">
    Introduce : 
    <input type="text" name="num"size="3"/>
    <br/>
    Numero 1 :
    <input type="text" name="A"size="3"/>
    <br/>
    Numero 2 :  
    <input type="text" name="B"size="3"/>
    <br/>
    Resultado : 
    <input type="text" name="submit"size="3"/>
    <br/>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calcular" />
    </p>

--->


<?php


    $operacion = $_POST['num'];
    $operacionA = $_POST['A'];
    $operacionB = $_POST['B'];
    $operacionC = $_POST['C'];
    $resultados = $_POST['resultados'];

    if(isset($_GET['resultados'])) {

        $resultado = $_GET;

    } else {

        $resultados = $_POST['resultados'];

    }

    if ($operacionA == "" && $operacionB == ""){ 

        echo "Introdusca Numero 1 y Numero 2 para realizar los calculos.";

    } elseif ($operacionB == "") {

        echo "Introdusca Numero 2 para realizar los calculos.";

    } elseif ($operacionA == "") {

        echo "Introdusca Numero 1 para realizar los calculos.";

    } else {

        if($operacion == "Sumar") {

            echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = $operacionA + $operacionB;

        } elseif ($operacion == "Restar") {

            echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = $operacionA - $operacionB;

        } elseif ($operacion == "Multiplicar") {

            echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = $operacionA * $operacionB;

        } elseif ($operacion == "Dividir") {

            if($operacionA<$operacionB){

                echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = $operacionA / $operacionB;

            } else {

                echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = $operacionB / $operacionA;

            }

        } elseif ($operacion == "Raiz Cuadrada") {

            echo 'La raiz cuadrada de A es : '.$resultado = sqrt($operacionA);
            echo '<br/>';
            echo 'La raiz cuadrada de B es : '.$resultado = sqrt($operacionB);
            echo '<br/>';

        } elseif ($operacion == "Porcentaje") {

            echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = ($operacionB * 100) / $operacionA;

        }

    }
    

    echo '<br/>';

    if ($operacionC == "") {

        echo "Introdusca Numero 3 para realizar los calculos.";

    }else{

        if($resultados == "Sumar") {

            echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = $resultado + $operacionC;

        } elseif ($resultados == "Restar") {

            echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = $resultado - $operacionC;

        } elseif ($resultados == "Multiplicar") {

            echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = $resultado * $operacionC;

        } elseif ($resultados == "Dividir") {

            if($operacionA<$operacionB){

                echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = $resultado / $operacionC;

            } else {

                echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = $resultado / $operacionC;

            }

        } elseif ($resultados == "Raiz Cuadrada") {

            echo 'La raiz cuadrada de A es : '.$resultado = sqrt($operacionA);
            echo '<br/>';
            echo 'La raiz cuadrada de B es : '.$resultado = sqrt($operacionB);
            echo '<br/>';
            echo 'La raiz cuadrada de C es : '.$resultado = sqrt($operacionC);
            echo '<br/>';

        } elseif ($resultados == "Porcentaje") {

            echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = ($resultados * 100) / $operacionC;

        }
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

El objetivo es que cuando ponga el numero 1 y 2 al calcular se mantenga el resultado y no se vacie

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: quieres que al darte el resultado no se borre los valores?

Comment: exacto es eso lo que yo quiero

Comment: Puedes colocar *calculadora.php* ?

Comment: es todo ese codigo

Comment: Alli te coloque tu codigo con POST dentro de tus Inputs prueba a ver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo tu código con el **POST** dentro de tus inputs

para que no se borre al generar tu resultado:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Calculadora Javi</title>
    <link href="index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){

    } else {
        $operacion = $_POST['operacion'];
    }

    echo "<br/>";
    echo '<h1>Calculadora Javi</h1>';
    echo '<br/>';

?>
<center>
<table>
    <form method="post" action="calculadora.php">
    <tr>    
        <td>
            <label for="num">Operacion 1 : </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="num">
                <option value="Sumar">Suma</option>
                <option value="Restar">Resta</option>
                <option value="Multiplicar">Producto</option>
                <option value="Dividir">Divisor</option>
                <option value="Raiz Cuadrada">Raiz Cuadrada</option>
                <option value="Porcentaje">Porcentaje</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Numero 1 :   
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['A']; ?>" name="A"size="8"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Numero 2 :   
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['B']; ?>" name="B"size="8"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="resultados">Operacion 2 :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="resultados">
                <option value="Sumar">Suma</option>
                <option value="Restar">Resta</option>
                <option value="Multiplicar">Producto</option>
                <option value="Dividir">Divisor</option>
                <option value="Raiz Cuadrada">Raiz Cuadrada</option>
                <option value="Porcentaje">Porcentaje</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Numero 3 : 
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['C']; ?>" name="C"size="8"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calcular" size="8" />
        </td>
        <td>
            
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</center>



<?php


    $operacion = $_POST['num'];
    $operacionA = $_POST['A'];
    $operacionB = $_POST['B'];
    $operacionC = $_POST['C'];
    $resultados = $_POST['resultados'];

    if(isset($_GET['resultados'])) {

        $resultado = $_GET;

    } else {

        $resultados = $_POST['resultados'];

    }

    if ($operacionA == "" && $operacionB == ""){ 

        echo "Introdusca Numero 1 y Numero 2 para realizar los calculos.";

    } elseif ($operacionB == "") {

        echo "Introdusca Numero 2 para realizar los calculos.";

    } elseif ($operacionA == "") {

        echo "Introdusca Numero 1 para realizar los calculos.";

    } else {

        if($operacion == "Sumar") {

            echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = $operacionA + $operacionB;

        } elseif ($operacion == "Restar") {

            echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = $operacionA - $operacionB;

        } elseif ($operacion == "Multiplicar") {

            echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = $operacionA * $operacionB;

        } elseif ($operacion == "Dividir") {

            if($operacionA<$operacionB){

                echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = $operacionA / $operacionB;

            } else {

                echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = $operacionB / $operacionA;

            }

        } elseif ($operacion == "Raiz Cuadrada") {

            echo 'La raiz cuadrada de A es : '.$resultado = sqrt($operacionA);
            echo '<br/>';
            echo 'La raiz cuadrada de B es : '.$resultado = sqrt($operacionB);
            echo '<br/>';

        } elseif ($operacion == "Porcentaje") {

            echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = ($operacionB * 100) / $operacionA;

        }

    }
    

    echo '<br/>';

    if ($operacionC == "") {

        echo "Introdusca Numero 3 para realizar los calculos.";

    }else{

        if($resultados == "Sumar") {

            echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = $resultado + $operacionC;

        } elseif ($resultados == "Restar") {

            echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = $resultado - $operacionC;

        } elseif ($resultados == "Multiplicar") {

            echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = $resultado * $operacionC;

        } elseif ($resultados == "Dividir") {

            if($operacionA<$operacionB){

                echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = $resultado / $operacionC;

            } else {

                echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = $resultado / $operacionC;

            }

        } elseif ($resultados == "Raiz Cuadrada") {

            echo 'La raiz cuadrada de A es : '.$resultado = sqrt($operacionA);
            echo '<br/>';
            echo 'La raiz cuadrada de B es : '.$resultado = sqrt($operacionB);
            echo '<br/>';
            echo 'La raiz cuadrada de C es : '.$resultado = sqrt($operacionC);
            echo '<br/>';

        } elseif ($resultados == "Porcentaje") {

            echo "El resultado es : ".$resultado = ($resultados * 100) / $operacionC;

        }
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias ahora mislo lo estoy probando

Comment: Dale nos avisas

Comment: me ha funcionado muchas gracias

Comment: Perfect, Saludos!